# ASP.NET URL Rewrite for directory and subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

In the web.config file in ASP.NET 
The URL Rewrite rule
    
        
            true

```
         <rule source="/somedirectory/" destination="/default.aspx" />

         <rule source="/somedirectory/another/" destination="/page01.aspx" />
```

The first one works fine but the second doesn't seem to work

How could i solve that

Comment: Try to move second rule to the top

Comment: try putting them the other way around, so the second one above the first. The second one is more specific, so it is possible that your url already matches with the first and so the second is skipped.

Comment: by doing that, it redirect to the root directory instead. (neither go to default.aspx nor page01.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using UrlMappings:

```
 <system.web>
     <urlMappings enabled="true">
         <add url="~/somedirectory/" mappedUrl="~/default.aspx"/>
         <add url="~/somedirectory/another/" mappedUrl="~/page01.aspx"/>
    </urlMappings>
 </system.web>
```

Make sure to use the '~' in the url and mappedUrl attributes.